# How to add tick or bar on color scale for levelplot in R

Tags: r, visualization, lattice, levelplot

Using the `levelplot` function from the `lattice` package, how can I add a tick or line to highlight a value on the color scale next to the level plot.

More specifically, I am plotting a covariance matrix as a heatmap and for example, I want to be able to indicate the level of significance on the color scale.

```
library(lattice)

mat <- matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5,nrow=5)
cov.m <-  cov(mat[,1:5],mat[1:5,])

levelplot(cov.m,  xlab="", ylab="", 
          col.regions= colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"), 
          space = "rgb"), cuts=100, at=seq(-0.2,1,0.005))
```

I now want to indicate 0.18 on the adjacent color scale.

**UPDATE**: so, I attempted to add an `abline` to `plot.trellis` and I do not get an error or a warning but it seems to be ignored. It could be that I'm not even hacking the source code correctly. Anybody with step-by-step instructions on how to modify the code in the lattice package in the context of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **yscale.components=yscale.raster.subticks**. For example:

```
levelplot(cov.m, 
       col.regions= colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"), space = "rgb"), 
       at=seq(-0.2,1,0.005)),
       yscale.components=yscale.raster.subticks,
       xscale.components=xscale.raster.subticks,
       margin=FALSE, 
       ylab='Y', 
       xlab='X', 
       main='Plot Name')
```

Answer (score -1):

(More of an extended comment on strategy than a final answer.) If you would desire to use grid plotting functons within the context of the `levelplot` code, you will need to do a "deep dive" into `lattice` and `grid` packages.

```
 methods(levelplot)
 getAnywhere(lattice.matrix)
 getAnywhere(lattice.formula)
 getAnywhere(construct.legend)
 lev <- levelplot(cov.m,  xlab="", ylab="", 
      col.regions= colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"), 
      space = "rgb"), cuts=100, at=seq(-0.2,1,0.005))
 lev$legend
 methods(print)
 getAnywhere(print.trellis)
 getAnywhere(plot.trellis)
```

The legend-drawing lines in the `plot.trellis` function are at the bottom. You could make a new `plot.trellis` and use `update.trellis` to modify the legend node of the lattice-object. Or you could hack around and attempt to position a grid-based annotation.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with R but I will try to follow as you say. IF you can get a working version of a hack for my example that'd be great

Comment: I guess my first attempt would be to hack the `plot.trellis` code to report the range of values used in the viewport that draws the colorkey. (But will not have time to experiment on this today, so someone else will need to do it.)